# How to specify Windows Main parameter nCmdShow

Tags: c, winapi

How do I specify the following nCmdShow parameter? Whats the command line argument name? Or is this parameter just used when using `CreateProcess`?

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPTSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
```

Should it be something like: `myexe.exe /nCmdShow=1`?

Comment: It is not provided on the command line. As you noted, if you launch an app it is provided via CreateProcess's `STARTUPINFO` parameter, and a separate parameter takes the command line. If you are not, programatically calling `CreateProcess` yourself you cannot really influence this flag - well - Shortcuts do have a field called "Run" (of all things) which sets it.

Comment: ok, the task scheduler is running my app, so I want it not visible when the TS runs it otherwise visible. So I guess I'll just pass a custom command line arg to handle whether it should be visible instead of using nCmdShow.

Comment: If its your app you can do that. But for other apps I'm sure you could create a shortcut and point task scheduler at that.

Comment: Windows sets it when appropriate and according to user request. For example, create a shortcut to your EXE, right-click on it and select Properties, go to the Shortcut tab, and change the Run combobox. Not really sure why you are asking. This is something the program should consume as a given, not something it should attempt to mess with or set for itself.

Answer (score -2):

`nCmdShow` has nothing to do with app command line. [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx) say next:

> Controls how the window is to be shown.

And the value is one of the `SW_*` codes. To check what exact value is passed - check application startup source code that should be available with Windows SDK (At least was for Platform SDK for w2k). For example see [here](https://github.com/leelwh/clib/blob/master/c/crt0.c#L309).

Comment: *"My guess is that this parameter is just legacy from old 16-bit Windows days, and actual value is always constant."* - No, it isn't. It's the value stored in *nShow* of [SHELLEXECUTEINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784.aspx), when calling `ShellExecuteEx`, or *wShowWindow* of [STARTUPINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331.aspx) when calling `CreateProcess`. See the *Remarks* section for [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, you're right: it is fetched from `STARTUPINFO` in some case. Correcting answer.

Comment: *"check application startup source code that should be available with Windows SDK"* - The CRT (and startup code therein) is part of the compiler. It doesn't ship with the SDK and never has. Besides, it isn't very enlightening: It simply calls [GetStartupInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683230.aspx).

Comment: "is part of the compiler" - CRT is a compiled code and it is better to say that it is part of SDK than a part of the compiler.

Comment: No, it isn't part of the SDK. The CRT is **strictly** part of the language implementation, i.e. compiler. You can write applications using the SDK, that do not use the CRT, and other compilers bring their own CRT (e.g. GCC).